# Automating DEM duplication using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dem

**Context:**

- I've imported a DEM of residential composed in several buildings.
- I've identified the max height of buildings by addind points in a layer for every building. Then I've integer an attribute field "max_height" and the value is the absolute altitude of the max Z of the building.

**Aim :**

For every building (around 150) I have to make a map that shows any object on the site higher than the max Z of the building (max_height).

**My need:**

I'm very new into GIS and the only way I know to exploit a DEM is to make a colored map.
That's why I would like to create colored maps where the color scale is based on a different height for building and the min value is the max z of the building (max_height), for every building.**

How can I automate this task?

Comment: I completely do not understand what you want to do and why. What does the verb "param" mean?

Comment: @Bernd V. Param = set. What I want to duplicated my DEM source and changing the "min" value of the new DEM. The aim is to create a new DEM that focus every feature I have to analyze, using the "max altitude of the building" as min value. Is it clear?

In writting this comment, I'm asking if I should not use Atlas instead ?

Comment: ahh, I start to begin to understand what you are after: So you need 150 different DEMs, where each DEM has the base at the "top" of a single building? Can I compare this to "flooding" the area, so the flood rises 150 times till the last building top is reached? What is Atlas?

Comment: I think it could be comparated to "flooding" the area (not sure to really understand the aim of this feature as well). But, my end is really to provide an single vizual analyze per building. I have to analyze everything located upper than the building. That's why I need 150 DEM (1per building).

By Altas tools  I meant : https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/forest_maps.html

Comment: What is a "single vizual analyze per building" ??? Do you want to make a viewshed analysis? What is the hole hocus-pocus good for? What has the Atlas to do with that task?  Really, if you do not present your task in an understandable way, I see a low chance to be able to contribute.

Comment: I'm really sorry to not be able to explain and to present my task better I'm doing : I'm really newbie in Qgis, and it is hard for me to use good term and to see which is the end of Qgis features.

Anyway, with "single vizual analyze per building" I meant my operational task: I have to use the DEM to localize every surface higher than every roof of building whatever the method I use, that is my mission.

My initial plan was to only duplicate the DEM and changing the "min value" of the DEM according to the building I'm analyzing.

Comment: Do you want a DEM each time or a colored map where the color scale is based on a different height?

Comment: A colored map where the color scale is based on a different height would be the best solution in my case.

Comment: " I have to use the DEM to localize every surface higher than every roof of building whatever the method I use, that is my mission" Again, such phrases make me even more confused. Especially when you are not sure how to solve a task, you really have to explain the problem from the end, and not the beginning and not in between. From them moment on you tell me and others WHY you have to do this, we can give you hints on HOW to accomplish it.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/bernd.vogelgesang/videos/10157191817910471/
Some time ago, a made a viewshed analysis for a windmill. In the video (set to highest resolution and full screen), you see the parts of the landscape coloured from red to green by the percentage of the windmill, an observer in the field can see. So in the red spots, the observer can see the windmill from bottom to top, orange the upper 75% and so on. But this is just one example of multiple things you can do with viewsheds etc.

Comment: @Bernd V. I've tried to explain again my aim, have a look into my original post.
If I understand well viewsheds feature, it is a colored map based on the height of a point and for the zone around this point, that could do the job